# Cypress automation project to use typescript?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am working on the cypress automation test, and it use plain js by default. 
Does it worth to convert it with type script?
Thanks in advance for your comment.

Comment: This question is unfortunately too open ended which is one of the reasons for closing questions at stack overflow. We like questions that have a clear answer

Comment: @JuanMendes What is the definition of too open ended? I felt it is legitimate technical question, and any one who have experience on this area will be able to have their opinion.

Comment: Whether to convert a project to Typescript depends on s lot of variables and team preference. This answer points out some benefits and also that it's a decision that needs to weigh the pros and cons. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739891/227299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct with the comments this is quite an open ended question. However I personally believe using TypeScript is a better option, we’ve converted all our Cypress project to TS more because of tech choice at our company. But personally I have experience with Java and TS is like JavaScript and Java’s love child. Personally I would give it a shout if you need any technical questions answered then please send me a message and I can help.

Comment: thanks for you comment. I am doing a POC now, but got difficults in converting the "index.js" under "plugins" and "support" folder. probably they can stay in js?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Typescript in your project, you can refer [this](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/use-typescript-with-cypress/).

I am using it in my project. There will be issues when you use some plugins such cypress-select-tests with Typescript. As they both share cypress-webpack-preprocessor, plugin don't work due to conflict. Otherwise, going with Typescript is a really good choice.